# Where do the two file descriptors of a pipe actually point to?

Tags: c, linux

I've read [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) about pipes, and I'm really unsure what it means by "returns
       two file descriptors, one referring to the read end of the pipe, the
       other referring to the write end".

The image I have in my head is like this: if the buffer in the pipe is a small region of memory, the write file descriptor points to the start of this region, and the read file descriptor points to the end of this region. The part which is confusing my is the fact it says the pipe has two ends. Figuratively yes, a pipe has two ends, but I don't understand how and why you read from something that points to the end.

If the write file descriptor points to the end instead, is writing to the buffer supposed to take the pointer to the end, shift back a few spaces depending on the size of the data to write, and write to that new position?

Comment: The "a pipe have two end" is a logical statement, not a physical one.

Comment: Whatever get written into the write file descriptor, by some kernel or userspace mechanism, get "piped" into the read file descriptor, in a FIFO manner; that is, if I write "123" into a pipe, the read end will get "123". If implemented using a buffer memory, the two file descriptor at first both points to the start of the buffer, and when k bytes are written, the write pointer moves k bytes; when k' bytes are read, the read pointer moves k' bytes.

Comment: @user12986714 Ok thanks, that makes more sense. Another question though: when does the write pointer move back to the start? I'd assume when the read pointer matches the write pointer, indicating that the receiving process has taken everything from the buffer.

Comment: Graphic illustrations of different pipe configurations are sometime helpful.  These are specific to pipes wired to write/read  to/from parent to child: [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=diagram+concept+of+software+fork+and+pipe()&client=firefox-b-1-d&channel=tus2&sxsrf=ALeKk03ABTv5SHRRq0bxAtAvJC_1z735GA:1588271366829&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=dyRzBB2YrrK2CM%253A%252CnVok7w25f4LKjM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRMaY0AYhetnI2LnNBbqgkxhm8Fmg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJq4H145DpAhUKv54KHU0kCyQQ9QEwAHoECAgQBQ#imgrc=lh4FSuOAS006mM&imgdii=ObvMLqCzjcnZ7M)

Comment: If the read pointer matches the write pointer (pipe is empty), the reading function, say `scanf()`, will wait until something got written into the pipe; As for when the write pointer returns, it depends on implementation; if it is implemented as a ring buffer, it will return at the end of the buffer; if it meets the read pointer (pipe is full), the writing function, say `printf()`, will wait until someone reads something from the pipe.